# Trying to connect to connect Google Sheet script to a Postgres Google Cloud SQL instance

Tags: postgresql, google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

I'm writing a script to connect a Google sheet to GCP Postgres instance, unfortunately I only see documentation for MySQL. Do you know if there is support for Google scripting/Postgres integration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Apps Script has JDBC connectors but they do not have support for Postgres as yet.

Currently Apps Script's JDBC connectors only support Cloud SQL(MySQL), MySQL, MSSQL, and Oracle databases as listed in the opening paragraph of the [JDBC documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc).

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to double check since Google says the JDBC connector supports Google Cloud Platform which PostgreSQL is also a product, pretty misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Apps Script JDBC connectors do not support Postgres, still. If you don't want to build your own script, you can use [database connector addons](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/search/database%20connector). Most of them support Postgres.